# Data validation problems in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a form with several labeled edits and radio buttons (grouped in radio groups) for the user to enter information, and a Save button to save the entries.  The Save button also closes the form.  If there are invalid entries (e.g., an alpha character instead of a number) or if some entries are left blank, I want to alert the user to correct the errors, and not close the form until there are no blank edit boxes or unchecked radio groups.  I do an error check separately for each edit box and radio group by means of raising a messageDlg alerting the user to the mistake.  However, if the user does not correct a mistake and tries to save the form, I want to keep the form open (not be able to close it) and alert the user to the mistake.  He should be able to close the form only after all the entries are valid and there are no unchecked radio groups.

Based on some replies to my earlier message, I have written the following code.  The first one is an example of data entry validation for one edit box (there are several such) and the second is the code for the OnClick event of my Save button.

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.lbleConstraintsMaxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  Val, ValidEntry: string;
  Chr: char;
  RangeMin, RangeMax: Double;
  const Allowed = ['0'..'9', '.'];
begin

  Val := lbleConstraintsMax.Text;

      //initialize values    
  ValidEntry := '';
  ConstraintsMaxChange := '';

  //value can contain only numerals, and "."
    for I := 1 to Length(Val) do
     begin
       Chr := Val[I];
       if not (Chr in Allowed) then
       begin
     MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
               'constraint must contain only a numeral, a decimal ' +
               'point or a negative sign.',
            mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
     Exit;

       end
       else ValidEntry := 'OK'; //validity check for this part

     end;

     //max value cannot be zero or less than the min value
    if not TryStrToFloat(Val, RangeMax) then Exit
    else if RangeMax = 0 then
    begin
       MessageDlg('Max value cannot be zero.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
       Exit;
    end
    else if not TryStrToFloat(lbleConstraintsMin.Text, RangeMin) then Exit
    else if RangeMax < RangeMin then
      begin
    MessageDlgPos('Max value cannot be less than Min value.',
           mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
      end

    else if (RangeMax < 0) then
      begin
    MessageDlgPos('A constraint cannot be negative.',
              mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
      end

    //final validity check
    else if ValidEntry = 'OK' then ConstraintsMaxChange := 'OK'
    else MessageDlgPos('There was an unexpected problem with the ' +
               'value entered in the max constraints box.',
            mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);

end;
```

And this is the code for the OnClick event of the Save button.  As you can see I am checking for the validity of several entries - and only if all of them are valid (that is have an 'OK' as the value of the corresponding variable), I allow the form to be closed.  it is raising the messageDlg correctly when there is an invalid entry. However, it is continuing to raise the messageDlg even after the error is corrected and the Save button is pressed.

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
//save input and output options
begin
    //check if all the option questions have been answered
    if not ((ConstraintsMinChange = 'OK') and //validation of correct entry as it is being entered
    (ConstraintsMinExit = 'OK') and //validation of entry as user is moving to another entry after an incorrect entry
    //several other such 'OK's 
      then
      begin
    MessageDlgPos('There is an invalid entry on the form.  Please ' +
              'correct it.', mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
      end


    else if //more messageDlgs if some other conditions are not met 

    else
      begin
      //save input and output options
      end;
     //finally if all the conditions are met, close the form 
    Close;
end;
```

Comment: `ModalResult` is only useful after the form (dialog) is closed. It has nothing to do with validating controls as you're trying to do. You need to check all the values, save them, and then use `ModalResult` in the code that launched the form to see if the dialog succeeded or not. (In other words, `ModalResult` is the return value of `ShowModal` to the code that displayed the form. It's really not meaningful or useful while the form is being used that returns it.) You should also not be checking numeric value, but use `mrOk`, `mrCancel`, and other proper `TModalResult` types.

Comment: I don't want them to be able to close the form unless all the entries are valid, though.  I have been looking but can't find anything similar to my problem.  Could you point me to or show me (in a very basic way) the code where one form (the data entry form) is launched from the main form, and ModalResult is used to validate  the values in the data entry form?  That would help a lot.

Comment: You can prevent the form from closing by setting CanClose to false in the OnCloseQuery event of the form.  The OnCloseQuery event fires before the OnClose event.

Comment: `OnCloseQuery` and `OnClose` are triggered even for modal Forms, so make sure you set `CanClose` to True/False accordingly. If you always set `CanClose` to False, or `CloseAction` to `caNone`, the Form will never close, even if its `ModalResult` is set.

Answer (score 3):

Set the button's `ModalResult` property to `mrNone` so it does not close the Form automatically, then have the `OnClick` event validate the entries as needed and set the Form's `ModalResult` property as needed only if they validate OK, eg:

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // check the entries as needed ...

  if (there is a validation error) then
  begin
    // do not close this form if there is an invalid entry
    MessageDlgPos('There is an invalid entry.  Please check and correct the entry.', mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300)
    Exit;
  end;

  // save all the entries into different variables ...

  // now close the Form
  ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

**Update:** based on your updates, try this instead:

```
type
  TfrmAnalysisOptions = class(TForm)
  private
    //...
    ConstraintsMinOK: Boolean;
    ConstraintsMaxOK: Boolean;
    //...
  end;

procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.lbleConstraintsMaxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  Val: string;
  Chr: char;
  RangeMin, RangeMax: Double;
begin
  //initialize values    
  ConstraintsMaxOK := False;

  Val := Trim(lbleConstraintsMax.Text);

  if not TryStrToFloat(Val, RangeMax) then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                  'constraint is not a valid numeric value.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  //max value cannot be zero or less than the min value

  if RangeMax < 0 then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                  'constraint cannot be negative.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  if RangeMax = 0 then
  begin
    MessageDlg('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
               'constraint cannot be zero.',
               mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  if not TryStrToFloat(lbleConstraintsMin.Text, RangeMin) then Exit;
  if RangeMax < RangeMin then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                  'constraint cannot be less than Min value.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  //final validity check
  ConstraintsMaxChange := True;
end;

procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (not ConstraintsMinOK) or
     (not ConstraintsMaxOK)
    //or several other such 'OK's missing
  then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('There is an invalid entry on the form.  Please ' +
                  'correct it.', mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  if //more messageDlgs if some other conditions are not met 
    //...
    Exit;
  end;

  //save input and output options...

  //finally if all the conditions are met, close the form 
  Close;
end;
```

Or better, don't do dynamic validation while the user is still entering data, that can lead to all kind of weird side effects if you are not careful.  Wait until the Save button is pressed instead, then validate everything:

```
function ValidateNumeric(const S, Desc: String; var Value: Double): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := TryStrToFloat(Trim(S), Value);
  if not Result then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the ' + Desc +
                  ' is not a valid numeric value.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  RangeMin, RangeMax: Double;
begin
  if not ValidateNumeric(lbleConstraintsMin.Text, 'min value of the constraint', RangeMin) then
  begin
    lbleConstraintsMin.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;

  if not ValidateNumeric(lbleConstraintsMax.Text, 'max value of the constraint', RangeMax) then
  begin
    lbleConstraintsMax.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;

  if RangeMax < 0 then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                  'constraint cannot be negative.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  if RangeMax = 0 then
  begin
    MessageDlg('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
               'constraint cannot be zero.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  if RangeMax < RangeMin then
  begin
    MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                  'constraint cannot be less than Min value.',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
  end;

  //more validations...
  //more messageDlgs if some other conditions are not met ...

  //save input and output options...

  //finally if all the conditions are met, close the form 
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: This catches the errors only as the form is being saved.  I have written validation code separately for each edit box and radio group, so that the errors are caught even as they are made (e.g., an alpha character instead of a number).  I found that even with these validations, the user was still allowed to proceed to make the other entries even if one was incorrect, and he could save the form.  I wanted to catch it at this stage too to make sure that incorrect entries were not saved.  I don't think the above code will do that, will it?

Comment: Remy’s approach will work provided your validation has a way to communicate the error(s) encountered to the `(there is a validation error)` in `btnSaveOptionsClick`.  I prefer to keep my validation code together, typically in the `OnCloseQuery`  event.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying.  For the validation of each edit box I save a public variable as 'OK' if validated.  Then on the OnClick event for the Save button, I check if all the public variables have an 'OK'.  If any one of them does not have an OK, then I raise a MessageDlg.  however, what I am finding is that if there is an error, the messageDlg is raised alright, but even after the error is corrected, this messageDlg continues to be raised.  Maybe I should forget about the individual separate validation and do it all in the onClick event of the Save button.

Comment: That suggests you are not tracking your validations correctly, so one or more of them is not OK when you need it to be. It would help if you update your question with more code showing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, @Remy.  I just edited my original message with code specific to my problem.

Comment: @Remy: Just saw it.  Thanks.  I am leaning towards your final suggestion of not doing dynamic validation, for I cannot delay it anymore, but I am surprised that it is so difficult.  I mean, it does look bad if I allow the user to enter a min value that is greater than a max value, but oh well!  I have had this up for a while and it looks like there is no real way of dynamic validation without weird effects, as you say.  Thanks, all, for your input, and  if I figure out something, I will post it here.

Comment: @user1505202: for things like min/max, you should use a TSpinEdit or TUpDown or equivalent, don't allow the user to enter a free-form text value. That makes validations and comparisons a little easier, since the values are presented to you as numerics, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a typical scheme how we treate modal result and validity:

```
procedure TSomeModalForm.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if ModalResult = mrOK then
    begin
      CanClose := CheckValidity;
      if CanClose then
        CanClose := SaveData;
    end
  else if dtsPacket.Modified then
    CanClose := dtsPacket.Cancel
  else if dtsNote.Modified then
    CanClose := dtsNote.Cancel
  else
    CanClose := TRUE;
end;
```

*CheckValidity* functions looks like this:

```
function TSomeModalForm.DoCheckValidity: boolean;
var
  InvCnt: Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited;
  InvCnt := 0;
  //
  HighlightInvalidValue(not edClient.IsEmpty, edClient, InvCnt);
  HighlightInvalidValue(not edBranch.IsEmpty, edBranch, InvCnt);
  HighlightInvalidValue(not edDstClient.IsEmpty, edDstClient, InvCnt);
  HighlightInvalidValue(not edDstBranch.IsEmpty, edDstBranch, InvCnt);
  //
  Result := Result and (InvCnt = 0);
  if not Result then
    ShowInErrBox(1);
end;
```

The code is based on our proprietary non VCL controls and assumes some validation support in a form ascendant, but a principle should be obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the sample, @pf1957.  I am a beginner and so I am having some semantic problems with the specifics of your code.  Thanks, though.  Clearly, there is a lot to learn.

Comment: OK. CheckValidity() is a method returning TRUE if form is valid, SaveData() is a method saving new values and returning TRUE if succeeded. Those dtsXXX.Modified properties are specific to our proprietary datasource (analogy of TDataSource) and indicate that some value in the form has been changed and ask an user for confirmation to close form without saving.

Comment: You are suggesting a function like your CheckValidity where the validity of each of the entries in my form is checked. It returns a True if everything is valid.  And to use this in the onClick event of my Save button. I guess the principle of this is what I am trying in my own way. I am doing a check at the OnChange event of each edit box and give a value 'OK' to a publicly declared variable if valid.  Then I check if all these variables have 'OK' on the OnClick event of my Save button.  Am working on this...

Comment: I just edited my original message with new code written based on my interpretation of the suggestion of @pf1957.  Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your place I would approach the problem differently. Since you want to perform your check when the **Save** button is clicked and report any data entry problems at once, I would run a validation process that would return all the error messages at once. It would allow the user to see and fix all the problems before the next attempt to save.

It would be something like this:

Add a `TMemo` Component to your form, make it **invisible and aligned as `alTop`**. This memo will hold all the error messages, if any, and will show them. A good idea is to put all your editing controls on a panel and align it as `alClient`.

The `OnClick` event handler of the **Save** button should have something like this:

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ErrorsMemo.Lines.Clear; // clear previous messages
  GetErrorMessages(ErrorsMemo.Lines); // run our error check and retrieve messages
  ErrorsMemo.Visible := ErrorsMemo.Lines.Count>0; // if there are messages, show them
  if not ErrorsMemo.Visible then  // if no errors are showing, close
    Close;
end;
```

The `GetErrorMessage` method will hold all the checks and will be something like

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.GetErrorMessages(aMessageList: TStrings);
var
  I: Integer;
  Chr: Char;
begin
  // Here you put all the checks and add the error message to aMessageList,
  // for instance:

  // value can contain only numerals, and "."
  for I := 1 to Length(Val) do
  begin
    Chr := Val[I];
    if not (Chr in Allowed) then
      aMessageList.Add('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
                       'constraint must contain only a numeral, a decimal ' +
                       'point or a negative sign.');

 // Other validations follow here...
```

end;

The main idea here is to separate your checking process from your message presentation and make the form closing process simpler.

Comment: I like your suggestion. On every `OnClick` event of my Save button, all the validations are done and any remaining errors are reported on the memo, and the form is allowed to close only when the memo field is blank. My only worry is that it may continue to trigger an error message when `RangeMax` < `RangeMin` (see my code) if for example, when the user enters 5 for the min and wants to enter 100 for the max, the debugger thinks that `RangeMax` is < `RangeMin` as soon as the user enters the "1" of the 100. That's what is happening now (being discussed in another post).

Comment: @user1505202: forgive me but I don´t see how this will continue to happen if all the validations will take place on the click of Save button. You will not validate values during typing anymone. The user will edit `RangeMin` and `RangeMax`, set any values and no check will be performed at this moment. When the Save button is clicked the check code will run, detect the invalid situation and add the proper error message. It seems to me that the problem will simply vannish.

Comment: I am sorry I did not see your reply. What I meant was that I want to do the validation when the user is entering the value as well as when saving the form. This problem was finally solved by using labels to alert the user of an incorrect entry rather than messageDlgs.  Thank you for your input.